# handleChange function causes dispatch function to return undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently learning about useReducer for react. I'm trying to make a recipe box with ingredients, measurements and amounts that you can change by typing inside the text-input boxes. But whenever I try to do the typing, the entire list disappears, and I get this error

```
react-dom.js:9 
        
       TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ingredients')
    at App (pen.js:63:26)
    at Bi (react-dom.js:7:19481)
    at ei (react-dom.js:9:3150)
    at oa (react-dom.js:9:44778)
    at la (react-dom.js:9:39715)
    at pf (react-dom.js:9:39646)
    at Ir (react-dom.js:9:39506)
    at so (react-dom.js:9:36651)
    at on (react-dom.js:7:3250)
    at Gi (react-dom.js:9:36960)
```

Each recipe seems to return "undefined" when I try to change any of the texts. I don't understand why the recipe parameter works before I type and not afterwards

This is the link to my code https://codepen.io/bl1xvan/pen/eYKmNbm?editors=0010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done a small mistake in the formReducer "CHANGE INGREDIENT" action. In your `formReducer`, dispatched action only returns the ingredients as the state. You need to keep the current recipe data and should only change the ingredients.

See the following change in the `formReducer`

```
const formReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CHANGE_INGREDIENT":
      return state.map((recipe) => {
        return {
          ...recipe,
          ingredients: recipe.ingredients.map((ingredient) => {
            if (ingredient.id === action.id) {
              return {
                ...ingredient,
                [action.payload.name]: action.payload.value
              };
            } else {
              return ingredient;
            }
          })
        };
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```